# Node not posting data when we request type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//app setup
var app = express();
//cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());
//session 
app.use(session(config.session));
// flash messages
app.use(flash());
//set path for static resources 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// set the path to view files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.disable('view cache');
```

**controller.js**

```
app.post('/inserData',function(req,res){
var requesData = req.body;
        cosnole.log('insert data');
        console.log(requesData);
})
```

**jqueryfile**

```
  $('#form').ajaxSubmit({
            url: "/inserData",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
```

from my jquery file i m posting data in my controller file but when try to print its given me blank data

below is my **request payload**

```
        ------WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

sadas
------WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="desc"

asdasdasd
------WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="log"; filename="Logo option 1 - Copy.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="back"


------WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5--
```

**request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytGkO6U6R5vf05na5
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/events
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:D291E8A4-B37F-45D0-BE72-5D76CFF81258
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: You're posting `multipart/form-data`, which `body-parser` doesn't support.

Comment: so how to handle such type of data

Comment: There are a few modules mentioned here: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser